# PHP-XML : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, xml

I was trying to display record from XML file. But I get following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice 
>   Message: Trying to get property of non-object 
>   Filename: controllers/events.php Line Number: 67

**xml file**

```
<events>   
  <event>
    <date>15/06/11</date>
    <venue>Parijs - Frankfort</venue>
    <name>SuperRunner 2011</name>
    <url>cgi-bin/phts.sh/x/xbevwindex.p?xtren=1234&amp;xmlac=np&amp;tpl=sp11</url>
  </event>
  . . . 
  . . . 
</events>
```

In my **controler 'events.php'**

```
function index(){
   $data['events'] = $this->readXMLFile();        
   $data['title'] = "Latest Events";
   $this->load->view('events/eventlistxml',$data);
}

function readXMLFile(){
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->load('events.xml');

        $events = $doc->getElementsByTagName("event");
        $data= array();
        foreach($events as $key=>$event):             
            $dates = $event->getElementsByTagName("date");
            $data[$key]['date'] = $dates->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $venues = $event->getElementsByTagName("venue");
            $data[$key]['venue'] = $venues->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $names = $event->getElementsByTagName("name");
            $data[$key]['name'] = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;

            $names = $event->getElementsByTagName("url");
            $data[$key]['url'] = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;
        endforeach;  
        return $data;
}
```

In **view 'events/eventlistxml.php'**

```
<?php                                     
 foreach($events as $key=>$val):                              
       echo $val['date']."<br />";
       echo $val['venue']."<br />";
       echo $val['url']."<br />";
       endforeach;
 ?>
```

This is due to url pattern in xml *cgi-bin/phts.sh/x/xbevwindex.p?xtren=1234&xmlac=np&tpl=sp11*
Is there any method to resolve this error?

Thank you for your kind support.

Comment: WHere is Line Number: 67 on file

Comment: which line of 67 in events.php?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to check if DOMDocument->load method returns TRUE first. Maybe your XML file is invalid in DOMDocument's perspective.
Try to add this:

```
function readXMLFile(){
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $res = $doc->load('events.xml');
  if (!$res) {
    echo("Failed to parse XML\n");
    return false
  }
...
```

Anyway, such verification is a good manner.
If it really returns FALSE, you should validate the structure of your XML.
You may add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

somewhere in the beginning of your php code. This will generate all warnings and notices of PHP-interpreter, so it may be helpful in understaning what's wrong.

Comment: Thans heximal but it shows error "Fail to parse XML". 
The above code displays all the record expect **URL**.
When I remove sub child <url> error disappears.

Comment: I see whats happening. You need to escape the slash symbols since it is reserved XML symbol, so parsing failing for fair reasons. Try to specify URL values in this manner: cgi-bin\/phts.sh\/x\/xbevwindex.p?xtren=1234&amp;xmlac=np&amp;tpl=sp11